# Netty and Channels and Websockets

Tags: websocket, netty, channel

So, I have built a Netty 3.6.2 based Websockets server application.  This application will have many, many users.

The idea is that clients register to listen for information on a topic, and when information flows through the server, the server sends the information to the clients.  Sound straightforward so far, right?

I implemented this by building a giant map held in memory mapping the topic to the client's  **Channel**.  When the server wants to send a message about a topic too all interested clients, it loops over all channels mapped to that topic.  Seem straightforward, right?

However, in some preliminary multi-user testing, I find myself realizing there is not a one-to-one mapping between channel and client.  How do I specifically target sending a message to a particular client if not through the channel?  I am at a loss....

Comment: Why is there not a one-to-one mapping between channel and client ? Is it because one client may have multiple open channels ?

Comment: I think there should be a 1-1 mapping.  But there is not.  When I look at the count of open channels, I have 7 open channels but 1000 users connected.  This makes no sense to me.  I can, however, see that 1000 channels were opened overall.. it's just that only 7 are open currently.

Comment: Wait, if there's only 7 channels, there's really only 7 physical connections, so how do you compute 1000 users ?

Comment: Clearly something goofy is going on.  I can see up to 89 open sockets with my netstat -ta on the linux machine, and 101 open channels.  My client thinks it has 200+ users connected concurrently. 

I conclude this is not a netty problem, this is a something-else-problem.

Comment: I forget what netstat **-ta** means, but I usually get the pid of my java process and do a **netstat -ap --numeric-ports | grep <pid>**

Answer (score 0):

There should be a one-one ratio of clients to open channels.  The fact that there is not is some sort of issue that is not related to netty.

Thank you for your help.